# How do I know if a path is short-circuited in Eagle PCB design

Tags: pcb-design, altium, eaglecad, short-circuit, pcb-layers

I am trying to make a 2-layer PCB design. At the bottom there is a battery case like this:

[image]

Left of (+) path is accidentally touched the ground. I saw that at bottom copper while exporting Garber file.

[image]

are there any automatic way to inform me "hey! Vcc touched the ground"

Also i saw at Altium program if user hower the lines, it show where is going like this. Are there same feature at eagle pcb software

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in the PCB design, or in the exported Gerber files, or in the program that imports Gerber files for viewing, or just how the Gerber viewer renders the data for viewing?

Comment: yes ı am sure , also I send to production and than device come and not working

Comment: @Justme I have added result image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am working with an old version of Eagle but I am sure these features still exist.

Re first question - shorted Copper Pad: While I am curious how Eagle let that happen in the first place, there is a feature called "Design Rule Check" (DRC for short).The button has a picture of a magnifying glass with traces. Using that feature, Eagle will check your whole design for clearance/electrical issues. If that feature doesn't detect a short of Vcc to GND that's probably a case for their support.

Re second question - highlight traces: Both in the schematic editor as well as the layout editor there is a button with a picture of an Eye, hovering over it it says "show". Activating that feature and clicking on a trace / connection will highlight that.

I recommend checking your Eagle version's manual and searching for the terms "DRC" and "highlight", you will find more information there.

Comment: thanks for EYE icon, but eye icon still not saying there are a short cut

Comment: @mehmet You asked two questions, the main one for the short and the second for highlighting. The eye icon feature only does the highlighting, it wont solve your short problem.
Have you tried using the DRC, the design rule check? That should give you a warning about different nets intersecting.